# JS and CSS bundling and minification in SharePoint 2013 - is that possible?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, bundling-and-minification

By default, SharePoint 2013 loads tons of javascript and some css.
My custom solution adds some more javascript and css.

How can I bundle and minify it (like standard bundling and minification functionality in asp.net 4.5)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Visual Studio extension called [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com).  Allows you to bundle and minify your JS and CSS.  It also has a lot of other great features.

Comment: I can bundle and minify my own css and js in many ways. But SharePoint itself loads tons of javascript. I wonder if I can bundle that ones.

Comment: The SharePoint solution you create should only have your custom JS and CSS... so not sure how you want to control what files SharePoint loads.  The SharePoint JS files are sitting in the layouts directory, you would have to copy all of them into your solution then minify and bundle... which doesn't make sense.

Comment: To perform this I will have to override all SharePoint standard functionality that automatically includes these files when needed. But if I want to override everything, I just do not use SharePoint. I wonder if I can tune the standard functionality without overriding it.